# Yii2: session cache problems when adding SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, yii, yii2

I am using Yii 2.0.12 and php 7.1. The problem is when I added SSL certificate to my websites, it starts an error when I validate forms with `POST` actions second time. Error is `Unable to verify your data submission.`

What I mean: I go for example to contact page and make `POST` action first time. Everything is ok. When I do it second and all next times, it raises an error.
But, if I add random param every time to page like `site.com/contacts?test=1`, everything works good.

The problem is in session verify (`csrf` perhaps) I guess.

I cleaned my .htaccess from cache files:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  # SSL redirect
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

also I removed `session` in `common.php`:

```
// 'session' => [
//     'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
//     'db' => 'db',
//     'sessionTable' => 'session',
// ],
```

also I removed `httpCache` from `behaviors()`.

On the other hand, on `localhost` I don't have this problems. Only after SSL added. My web hosting includes php modules:

```
ctype, curl, dom, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, hash, iconv, imagick, intl, json, mbstring, mcrypt, mysqli, opcache, openssl, pdo, pdo_mysql, session, simplexml, soap, sockets, timezonedb, tokenizer, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xsl, zip
```

Apache:

```
autoindex_module, cgi_module, expires_module, headers_module, php_module, rewrite_module,
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: you might need to update the framework as there were several fixes for `csrf` token like `Enh #14087:` or **`Bug #14542:` Ensured only ASCII characters are in CSRF cookie value since binary data causes issues with ModSecurity and some browser** that were done in 2.0.13, and 4 more bugs related up to version `2.0.16`. see [`change-log`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Also worth to check if CSRF cookie configuration is set to `secure` - `'components' => ['request' => ['csrfCookie' => ['httpOnly' => true, 'secure' => true]]]`

Comment: @Bizley, where did you find `secure` attribute? https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php#L133

Comment: @sirjay in [Cookie](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Cookie.php#L44)